# Incorrect Json in output toJson method of Gson library

Tags: java, json, gson, marshalling

I use method toJson for generate json from object. I encountered an error with the translation of the object into the json view .

```
    SingnUpRq singnUpRq = new SingnUpRq("lsjdflkdjslfk", "ZCqKckIpwvxtLFZz3TlUln5RqUpEB5U43imi7PSYv6UBY/bLvKQBSDIxXR5cAKnK+CU+UiyBB998fRJRvGJJDw==");

    String postBody = gson.toJson(singnUpRq);

    postBody (problem with last symbols == :{"DeviceId":"lsjdflkdjslfk","RefreshToken":"ZCqKckIpwvxtLFZz3TlUln5RqUpEB5U43imi7PSYv6UBY/bLvKQBSDIxXR5cAKnK+CU+UiyBB998fRJRvGJJDw\u003d\u003d"}
```

Why is this problem may occurr?
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: How do you initialize Gson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution here: 
https://github.com/google/gson/issues/203

Instead use constructor `new Gson()`, need use

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
```